# Exporting details of specific category

Tags: product, category, export

How to export details of products belonging to specific category .

Default export option exports complete list of products from all categories.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. What you can do is export all products and then filter the list by the category row.

The alternative is to change `\Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product::export` especially `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php:604` to filter by category.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be some direct method to export specific category from admin panel